Ruby on Rails redirecting with OPTION instead of GET
my code is redirecting with a options requisition instead of a get, what could cause that?
the redirecting comes from here:
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to "#{YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/sso.yml")[Rails.env]["provider_url"]}/logout?redirect=#{root_url}", allow_other_host: true
  end

returns this error on the another application:

Started OPTIONS "/logout?redirect=http://localhost:3009/" for ::1 at
2024-09-18 15:16:29 -0300    ActionController::RoutingError (No route
matches [OPTIONS] "/logout"):

Rails 7.0.8.4
ruby 2.7.8p225

Destroy is not typically a GET

The issue is likely surrounding the call.  How are you calling this action?

In that case is a GET because it's linked to a sso application

redirect with status: :see_other

Paste all surrounding requests as seen in your browser console. My guess is the redirect response (302 or whatever) goes through just fine, but then your browser makes an OPTIONS request due to CORS before redirecting and your app doesn’t know how to respond to the OPTIONS request.

@DennisHackethal i think that's exactly the problem, but how could i solve this? tried to add a options route, but that doesn't work

As I wrote in my comment, this is an issue with CORS.
Something like this article should help you configure your Rails app to respond to the OPTIONS request appropriately. You’d install the rack-cors gem and add an initializer that tells your app which domain it should accept requests from:

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://example.com:80'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post]
  end
end


